# Mysql Unable to store values to database with specific characters

Tags: java, mysql

My code in mysql:

```
`SET NAMES 'utf8';`    `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';`    `SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci';`    `insert into test (regOznaka) values ("NS 247 SČ"), ("NS 247 SĆ"), ("NS 247 SC");`
```

result is:

```
Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry 'NS 247 SĆ' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: You have duplicate the prinary key, should add different value

Answer (score 0):

> A primary key, also called a primary keyword, is a key in a relational database that is unique for each record. It is a unique identifier, such as a driver license number, telephone number (including area code), or vehicle identification number (VIN). A relational database must always have one and only one primary key.

Here is the syntax to define ID attribute as a primary key in a CUSTOMERS table.

```
 REATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),       
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

for you query you should inert value different than 'NS 247 SĆ'

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is a value that must be stored into database, these three values is a real values, like vehicle identification number, but in serbian language. In my applications might be and combination like "NS 100 SS" and "NS 100 SŠ" which is NOT equal, but mysql not accepted this